# c program is not showing correct age

Tags: c

Why is my C program not showing the correct age? im on codeblock with stock compiler. it keeps showing 50. Im lost as to why that would be. Also i tried it here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php. it shows the age as zero.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int age;
    int currentYear;
    int birthYear;

    age = currentYear - birthYear;
    currentYear = 2016;
    birthYear = 2000;

    printf ("You are %d years old. It is now:%d. It began in:%d.", age, currentYear, birthYear);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to study a minimum of utterly basic programming before asking questions here. SO is a site for professional and enthusiast _programmers_.

Answer (score 4):

```
// change the order

currentYear = 2016;
birthYear = 2000;
age = currentYear - birthYear;
```

**Conclusions**

1. Automatic variables which are not initialized are in **an indeterminate stage**, so you got non-sensical values for age.
2. Also, expressions are **usually** evaluated in the order which they are present in the code. Logically it makes sense to put `age = currentYear - birthYear;` at the end.

**Reference**

ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.79->10

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, its value is indeterminate.

Answer (score 2):

Reorder

```
age = currentYear - birthYear;
currentYear = 2016;
birthYear = 2000;
```

to

```
currentYear = 2016;
birthYear = 2000;
age = currentYear - birthYear;
```

You first took the difference of 2 uninitialized variables (which is bad because the result is undefined) and only then you set the two year variables.

Answer (score 0):

Because you subtracting unassigned variables. You should place `age = currentYear - birthYear;` after assigning values to `currentYear` and `birthYear`.